# Comparing char values from arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, char

Okay so my program is made up of two classes, DriverMain & DriverExam. In the DriverExam class a char array is created and filled with answers (correct) and then in the main the user will enter their answers and it's stored into a char array called correctAns. I'm having trouble comparing the value of any char in each array to each other in order to see if the user's answers are correct.

Here's the DriverMain class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DriverMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create studetnAns array and studentOne
    char[] studentAns = new char[5];
    DriverExam studentOne = new DriverExam();

    // While loop will keep question running until
    // the user has filled up the array
    while(studentAns.length < 4) {

        for (int i = 0; i < studentAns.length; i++) {

            // Load array with user's answers
            char ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter an answer").charAt(0);
            studentAns[i] = ans;
        }
    }

    // Testing getTotalCorrect method
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total answers correct is " + studentOne.getTotalCorrect(studentAns));
}
```

}

And here's the DriverExam class:

```
public class DriverExam {

// Instance variables
int correct;
int incorrect;
char [] correctAns;

/**
 * 
 */
public DriverExam() {

    char[] correctAns = {'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C'};

    correct = 0;
    incorrect = 0;
}

public int getTotalCorrect(char[] studentAns) {

    for (int i = 0; i < studentAns.length; i++) {

        if (studentAns[i] == (correctAns[i])) {

            correct += 1;
        }
    }

    return correct;
}

public boolean passed() {

    boolean pass = false;

    return pass;
}
```

}

Comment: Arrays aren't dynamically sized, so your `while` loop is never entered. `studentAns` has a (constant) `length` of `5`.

Comment: So how would I get it work then?

Comment: **Remove** the `while` loop, your `for` loop should then run.

Comment: It runs but it crashes after the array is full. Eclipse says' there is an error with how I'm comparing the char's in the getTotalCorrect() method.

Comment: Change `char[] correctAns = {'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C'};` in the `DriverExam` constructor to `correctAns = {'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C'};`, you're shadowing the field.

Comment: Ohh and it works but the counter for my number of correct answers is 0 even if I put all the correct tanswers